# NodeJs How can i show first 3 authors in my model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I made a simple api. With 3 tables.(collections with mongodb). Like Collections-Authors-Articles. I want to show 3 author on collections but i cant found how can i do it ? When i send get request to collections on postman i need to see like;

```
  "name":xxx;
    "icon":xxx;
    "authors":{
              authorid,
              authorid,
              authorid }
```

My Schemes :

article.js =

```
const { db } = require("../collection");

const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Articles = Schema({
  author: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Authors",
  },
  collectionid: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Collections",
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  createddate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  updateddate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Articles", Articles);
```

author.js =

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;
  
var Authors = Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Authors", Authors);
```

collections.js =

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Collections = Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  icon: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Collections", Collections);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `populate` to populate collection authors, see the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)